# Overriding func +( [ Double ], [ Double ] )

Tags: swift, foundation

I want to define `+ function` of `[ Double ]` like below.

```
[ 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 ] + [ 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 ] -> [ 7.0, 9.0, 11.0 ]
```

So, I defined `+ function` like below.

```
func +( _ l: [ Double ], _ r: [ Double ] ) -> [ Double ] {
    guard l.count == r.count else { fatalError() }
    var v = [ Double ]( repeating: 0, count: l.count )

    // Some adding operation

    return v
}
```

**It works unless without Foundation framework.**

But when I include Foundation framework, it seems that in Foundation framework `+( Array, Array )` has been already defined. So,

```
[ 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 ] + [ 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 ]
```

gets

```
[ 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 ]
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this? Or is overriding `+([ Double ],[ Double ])` alongside `Foundation framework` impossible?

Comment: Did you try adding the `override` keyword?

Comment: Is there an option to use `++` as an operator?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Thanks, but adding override keyword makes error. `'override' can only be specified on class members`

Comment: @Eimantas I'm now using `infix operator ++`, but I wanna use + if I can.

Comment: @Satachito the `+` operator for `Double` (and any type of array) is used for concatenation (including `String` type too). So you're out of luck unless you want to swim against quite matured convention.

Comment: What is `vDSP_vaddD`?

Comment: @Cristik quite common Apple native functions of Accelerate's DSP library, but I agree it should've been included/described in the OP's question.

Comment: Just tried the operator, and the override works, provided the override is declared before performing the operation.

Answer (score 2):

As `+` for two `Array` operands has already been [reserved for concatenating arrays](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray/2963720), you'd have to resort to declaring your own `infix` operator. E.g. `~+`:

```
import Accelerate

infix operator ~+

func ~+( _ l: [ Double ], _ r: [ Double ] ) -> [ Double ] {
    guard l.count == r.count else { fatalError() }
    var v = [ Double ]( repeating: 0, count: l.count )
    vDSP_vaddD( l, 1, r, 1, &v, 1, vDSP_Length( v.count ) )
    return v
}

print([ 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 ] ~+ [ 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 ]) // [7.0, 9.0, 11.0]
```